# Cold storage/WORM on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a requirement that states certain data in my application must be write once, read many. Is there a construct or best practice approach on Azure that would facilitate this?

Comment: What, specifically is your question? There's no 'best practice' because it'll be app-specific and product-specific.There are multiple native services used for storing/retrieving data in Azure (storage blobs/tables as you tagged your question, DocumentDB, SQL Database) as well as 3rd-party solutions in VMs+attached disks. This question is super-broad and opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not have any best practice on this topic but I can think of two options which might work:

Option 1: Use Append Block, a new blob type which is currently available with the newest storage service version. All writes to an Append Blob happen at the end of the blob. Updating and deleting existing blocks is not supported. To modify an Append Blob, you add blocks to the end of the blob via the new Append Block operation. Each appended block is accessible immediately. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/04/13/introducing-azure-storage-append-blob.aspx has more information about Storage Append Blob.

Option 2: You can take snapshots of your blobs very frequently as snapshots are read-only copy of your original blobs. However, someone who has an authorized access to snapshots will be able to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

We now have cold storage refer http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-launches-cool-blob-azure-storage-at-1c-per-gb/. Hope this helps